# Selenium (Node.js) screenshots are too slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, mocha.js, screenshot

I am using Selenium + Mocha (in Node.js) to do some UI testing on a site.  After each test, I want to capture a screen shot so that I can review/share the visible results.

However, after the basic UI changes are made (i.e. insert text and hit submit), there is an AJAX call + JavaScript animation that triggers after that I would like to be part of my screen shot.

The screenshots I'm getting appear to be in taken after the next step has already started. (So, the first test runs > trigger the screenshot > second test starts > screenshot is actually captured)

I've tried `.sleep()` and timeouts -- however my use could have been wrong.

```js
function takeScreenshot(name='out'){
      driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data){
        var base64Data = data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,"")
        fs.writeFile(`screenshots/${name}.png`, base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
          if(err) console.log(err);
        });
      });
}

describe('UI Tests', async function() {

  before(async function() {
    driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    await driver.get('http://localhost:8000').then( async function(){ await getAssets(); });
    /* search | submit | reset are declared in getAssets() */
  });

  after(async function() {
    driver.quit();
  });

  afterEach(async function(){
    step++;
    driver.sleep(3000).then(
      takeScreenshot(step) 
    );
  });

  describe('User Types/Modifies Input and Submits Query', async function() {

    it('type in search + click submit', async function(){
        search.sendKeys("Puppies and Kittens");
        submit.click();
    });

    it('click the X icon to clear search', async function(){
        reset.click();
    });

  });

});
```

In the above snippet, the screenshot for the first test (`'type in search + click submit'`) would show the input field already cleared from the second test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands being sent to selenium are asynchronous, meaning a function will schedule the work to run at some point in the future but return immediately so the code moves on.

In selenium-webdrivers case, the functions return a "promise" that will resolve at some point in the future. Mocha can use a promise to wait for the result.

#### Promises and Mocha

Mocha uses the return value of a test to determine if it should wait for a promise to resolve. You can control promise flow with `await` or `.then`.

If [Promise A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) code is being used, then you will always have `return someFormOfPromise` in the test.

```
it(waits, function(){
  return Promise.resolve(true)
    .then(res => expect(res).to.be.true)
})
```

If [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) is being used, that guarantees a promise is returned but you must [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) anything asynchronous or the tests will continue on

```
it(waits, async function(){
  let res = await Promise.resolve(true)
  expect(res).to.be.true
})
```

Callbacks are similar, but they use a `done` function to signal the tests to move on.

```
it(waits, function(done){
  someTrueCallback((err, res) => {
    if (err) return done(err)
    expect(res).to.be.true
    done()
  }) 
})
```

There's a lot of mixed [Promise A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) and [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in the posted code, there's even a callback thrown in. Pick one way and stick with it where possible, I'll use [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

#### Callback to Promise

Any asynchronous callbacks can be converted to promises, so starting with the [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) callback function, turn it into a promise:

```
function writeFile(path, data, format){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    fs.writeFile(path, data, format, function(err){
      if (err) return reject(err)
      resolve(true)
    })
  })
}
```

Luckily this is pretty standard and Node.js has a helper for this in [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) so the helpers can become:

```
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)

function async takeScreenshot(name='out'){
    let data = await driver.takeScreenshot()
    var base64Data = data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,"")
    return await writeFile(`screenshots/${name}.png`, base64Data, 'base64')
}
```

#### Tests

There's no need to use `.then` when [`await`](http://await%20-%20JavaScript%20%7C%20MDN) is available.

Whenever a function returning a promise is called, you probably need an `await` or `let res = await...` if you want to use the resolved value.

```
describe('UI Tests', function() {

  before(async function() {
    driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    await driver.get('http://localhost:8000')
    await getAssets()
    /* search | submit | reset are declared in getAssets() */
  });

  after(async function() {
    await driver.quit();
  });

  afterEach(async function(){
    step++;
    await takeScreenshot(step) 
  });

  describe('User Types/Modifies Input and Submits Query', function() {

    it('type in search + click submit', async function(){
        await search.sendKeys("Puppies and Kittens");
        await submit.click();
    });

    it('click the X icon to clear search', async function(){
        await reset.click();
    });

  });

});
```

As a side note these tests aren't actually checking anything. Normally an assertion library like [chai](http://chaijs.com/) would be used to ensure things are the way you [expect](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/).

Comment: Thank you for the amazing write-up and explanation :)  I'm a (obviously) a little green with testing; so I wasn't certain on how granular to break down the tests -- for brevity, I didn't include every test, but I do have some where it actually checks for expected values.  Regardless, I'm now looking into chai as well.  Thank you again.

Comment: No worries. Once the async/promise stuff clicks all of node becomes a lot easier!